# Progress image till response arrive in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I working with Angular 4. I was trying to implement progress image till response arrive back from API to web application. 
Earlier I was using HTTP library of Angular 4(@angular/http) then ng-busy works with that but I am not getting any option for HttpClient library ('@angular/common/http').

If anyone has any idea/example at plunker then that would be helpful

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your question it is unclear if you meant you where using ng-busy in AngularJS or Angular.

Have you looked into this library? https://github.com/mpalourdio/ng-http-loader/blob/master/README.MD

There are a few of the like this. You can also look to do this yourself by setting up an interceptor.

https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-interceptors/

Comment: I have mentioned, application is on angular 4.

Comment: Yes but you said "earlier I was using Http and ng-busy" and it is unclear what you mean by earlier. What is earlier. Earlier today, in AngularJS or Angular version 2, etc.

Comment: Pardon me, I should be more clear. I have tried your solution but they don't work. Your solution works with @angular/http library but i have moved to "'@angular/common/http'" library for making a get,post request.

Comment: Updated my answer to point to a new library that works with that module. I have not used that library but it should at least provide an example.